# Hexagon problem with a body, how i can remove them?

Tags: subdivision-surface, soft-body

Someone can help me? How can i remove this hexagons?[image]

After selecting all similar faces
[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot with some of these ngon faces selected? Eg in face select mode select one hexagon, then select > similar > polygon sides.

Comment: Done, now what?

Comment: Wondered if you had dupe mesh below.   See  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84520/removing-triangles-and-ngons   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78578/optimizing-mesh-to-quads-only   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/205702/how-to-fill-ngon-with-quads  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/199830/convert-polygons-or-ngons-to-quads-using-bmesh  If not mentioned one method is to poke (adds a center vert and contect making a triangular fan, then tris to quads.  Do you know how it got that way?

Comment: I joined two objects with the "boleans" modifier, I set join, not difference, and I smoothed the corners in sculpting mode

Comment: sorry man, but what you recommended me, doen't work. Any others tip?

Comment: IDK ... It looks beyond easy fixing..  if it was me would consider starting again and not apply modifiers (easier to fix pre-subsurf), or else clean by removing  the "frayed bits" to manageable   seams and fill holes with grid fill or bridge etc. Would  Also consider making the question title more explanatory of your issue   "Mesh trashed after ... can it be fixed."?